# Significato di "farle buone" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La luna e i falò*, di Cesare Pavese, ho letto:

> Poi s’apriva la porta, la signora Elvira cacciava dentro la piccola Santina di corsa, e Arturo si alzava in piedi, salutava seccato, la signora diceva: – Abbiamo ancora una signorina gelosa, che vuol essere presentata –. Poi arrivava il sor Matteo che ce l’aveva su con lui, ma la signora Elvira invece **gliele faceva buone** e trovava che per Irene andava benissimo anche Arturo.

Il significato di "avercela su con qualcuno" (cioè, "provare  nei  suoi  confronti  anti­patia, rancore"), che non conoscevo, l'ho potuto leggere sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI01/GDLI_01_ocr_885.pdf&parola=avercela). Comunque, non ho trovato cosa vuol dire "farle buone", espressione che ho cercato alla voce "buono" di alcuni dizionari, anche se posso immaginare che si tratti di qualche sorta di contrario. Potreste spiegarmi che significa?

Comment: È un'espressione che secondo me significa che la signora Elvira faceva passare per buone (=lasciava correre, perdonava) le maniere screanzate di Arturo.

Answer (score 2):

È un'espressione che secondo me significa che la signora Elvira faceva passare per buone (ovvero lasciava correre, perdonava, autorizzava in qualche modo) le maniere screanzate di Arturo.

Un'espressione simile è *abbuonare* - prendo la definizione da qui: https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/A/abbuonare.shtml

> in senso fig., perdonare qlco. a qlcu.: ti abbuono questa scappatella